# When an object was added to Caffeine cache

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot caching in a project and am using Caffiene. I've added some default configuration for Caffeine to the project, and I can get the most recent object from the cache using the following code:

```
private final CaffeineCache caffeineCache = (CaffeineCache) caffeineCacheManager.getCache("myCacheName");
Cache<Object, Object> cache = this.caffeineCache.getNativeCache();
cache.policy().eviction().get().hottest(1);
```

I don't actually want the object itself, but I'd want to know when it was added to the cache. Is there a way to find out when this object was added to the cache?

Comment: The expiration/refresh time stamps are available if those configurations are used. Otherwise you could capture the time in your own field, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ben! I'll  look into the expiration and refresh timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ben Maines comment, I found a solution to my problem. I calculated the cache time using the expiration timestamp:

```
CacheResponse cacheResponse = new CacheResponse();
    Cache<Object, Object> cache = this.caffeineCache.getNativeCache();
     if(cache.policy().eviction().get().hottest(1).keySet().iterator().hasNext()) {
        // Time in milliseconds since object was cached
        OptionalLong time = cache.policy().expireAfterWrite().get().ageOf(cache.policy().eviction().get().hottest(1).keySet().iterator().next(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        LOGGER.info("Calculating last UTC cached date");
        // Calculate last cached time and set the object in the cache response
        cacheResponse.setTime(Instant.now().minusMillis(time.getAsLong()).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime());
    } else {
        LOGGER.info("Cache appears to be empty.");
    }
    cacheResponse.setNumCachedItems(cache.estimatedSize());
    return cacheResponse;
```

Comment: The last release added java.time overloads, which would help your calculation. You could also store the policies to variables to avoid the noise. Glad it works!